# How to create a consistently sized internal rectangle inside a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a UserControl that has a grid in it.  Inside the grid is a rectangle that covers all columns except the first and last column and all rows except the first and last row.  The UserControl will change shape to fit its parent object and the distance from the edge of the UserControl to the rectangle should be consistent all the way around.

My first try, I used percentages in ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition but this only works correctly when the UserControl is square.  Otherwise the distance from the rectangle to the edge of the UserControl is not consistent between the top/bottom and sides.

My second try, I tried binding to the Width of one of the last column and first and last row of the grid to the ActualWidth of the first column.  This did not work. None of the sides were same distance from the rectangle to the UserControl edge.

My third try, it occurred to me that I need to get the ratio of the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the UserControl and then use that to set the width of the first and last column of the grid as well as the first and last row of the grid.  I tried this calculation in the Loaded event but that did not work AND it would not work when the UserControl is resized.

I am at a loss.  Does anyone know how to conquer this?

Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Example]

The blue area is the User control.  They Vanilla area is the rectangle inside.  I manually set column widths and row heights to make it look like i want.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. What is the purpose of the outer rows and columns? Why does a Margin around the Grid not work? Perhaps show us a sketch.

Comment: @Clemens, I edited my original post to add an image of what I am trying to accompish.

Comment: Not sure what we are supposed to see there. How about setting the Grid's Margin?

Comment: @Clemens, The blue area needs to be visible because I flash it Red when a particular event happens.   

This control will be used on systems with various resolutions and margin is pixel value, it is not a percentage value.  If I use a static margin and design it on a 640x480, the blue area is just a sliver when shown on a 2560x1600 system.  Inversely, if I design it on a 2560x1600, the blue area is huge.  That is why I am looking for some way to use a consistent percentage around the shape.

Comment: Put the Grid in an outer 3x3 Grid with appropriate relative row and column sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a control with a border whose dimension is some proportion of either the control's width/height or the screen's.

The following is a simple `UserControl` that I quickly mocked-up:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public sealed class ConsistentBorderControl : UserControl
    {
        protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
        {
            base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
            double dimension = sizeInfo.NewSize.Width * 0.1;
            Tag = new Thickness(dimension);
        }
    }
}
```

It's hooking into the `RenderSizeChanged` event and calculating the dimension of the border as being 10% of the control's current width. It then uses this to create a uniform `Thickness` and puts that in the `Tag` property (you would probably be better using a custom dependency property to hold this thickness value).

Then in the XAML, inside the UserControl, we can simply create a `Border` element whose `BorderThickness` binds to the `Tag` property of its parent:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <local:ConsistentBorderControl x:Name="parent">
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="{Binding Tag, ElementName=parent}">
           <Grid ... >
        </Border>
    </local:ConsistentBorderControl>
</Window>
```

You could also base the border dimension on the size of the screen, by using `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea` instead of the render size of the control. (However this will only work for the main screen, accessing multiple monitor dimensions is a bit trickier in WPF).